# Sending to SQL database via the URL

Tags: php, sql, url

I am having a little difficulty in saving values via the URL into a SQL database.  I can explicitly put in values into the the INSERT command, but that is not what I want.
Say I had a URL like the following:
and code like the following:

```
<?php
include 'curr.php';
$url = curPageURL();
$query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query = parse_str($query_str, $query_params);
$fn = $_REQUEST['Firstname'];$sn = $_REQUEST['Surname'];
$link = mysql_connect('server.co.li', 'username', 'pass333');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
$sql = 'INSERT INTO p_database '.
       '(Firstname, Surname) '.
       'VALUES ($fn, $sn)';

mysql_select_db('my_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $link );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I have tried $_Get and $_POST as well as $_REQUEST to get the information, and here is the error that is produced when I run:
"*Connected successfullyCould not enter data: Unknown column '$fn' in 'field list'*"

Any assistance would be appreciated.
(P.s. I know the code is not secure or safe, that will come after the functional parts are complete).

Comment: Try `$sql = "INSERT INTO p_database "." (Firstname, Surname) "." VALUES ('$fn', '$sn')";`

Comment: Thanks for the answers people, solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are incorrect,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO p_database ".
       "(Firstname, Surname) ".
       "VALUES ('$fn', '$sn')";
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Quicknote: Shouldn't those values be quoted? `('$fn', '$sn')` since they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your $fn and $sn like so:

$sql = "INSERT INTO p_database (Firstname, Surname) VALUES ('$fn', '$sn')";